# How to verify EBS and RDS in VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I believe that I've successfully setup an EBS instance and RDS instance in a VPC! It is structured like this:

- **Elastic load balancer**: public available to the internet
- **Elastic instance**: in private subnets
- **RDS instance**: in private subnets

What can I do, **both in AWS and outside through testing**, to verify that my elastic instance is protected in the VPC and my RDS instance is as well?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify the following:

1. ensure that SGs of the instances allow only **incoming traffic from the SG of ALB**.
2. ensure that the EB instances are in **private subnet**, i.e. they don't have public IP.
3. ensure that RDS has **no public IP** option enabled and also it is in private subnets.
4. also ensure that the SG of the RDS allows only **incoming connections from the EB instances**.

Comment: Thanks for the help Marcin!! For 1. Should this be allowing incoming traffic from the **SG on HTTP or HTTPS?**

Comment: @NGI Hi. Usually its HTTP, unless you have specific requirement for end-to-end ssl encryption.

Comment: I see, just to confirm, would end-to-end ssl be more secure?

Comment: @NGI Yes, but this requires more settings and changes on the ALB and your EB instances. It will not work out of the box.

Comment: Ok this makes sense. Sorry for going on and on, but does this mean I can't just change the inbound rule on the SG?

Comment: At present your instances use HTTP, so you need to allow this in the SG of the instances. For HTTPS between ALB and the instances, you need HTTPS listener on the ALB, self-signed SSL certificates on the instances and re-configured nginx to use the ssl.

Comment: Dang, ok, I see. Thanks again for your help Marcin!! Learning a lot from you :-)

Comment: @NGI No problem. You are progressing very fast :-)

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @Marcin's comments, I would also do the below to ensure you are following best practises:

- Enabling access logs on the ELB to have some sort of logs on who is accessing the ELB. Would definitely help in troubleshooting.
- Have your ec2 in ASG.
- Create a certificate and terminate the HTTPS connections on ELB or you can pass the HTTPS through and terminate the SSL on the ec2.
- Redirect all requests from the http port to https using the redirect feature in ELB.

Now, to answer your question on how to test the security:

- try to ssh into your ec2 directly. It should not work as you are only allowing traffic from ELB and your ec2 is in private subnets.
- try accessing your RDS. It should not work as it will only allow traffic from EC2 security group
- Build a bastion server (a blank ec2) on AWS and try to access the EC2. It should not work as the ec2 should only allow traffic from the ELB security group
- using the bastion, try accessing RDS. Same as above, it should not work as it should only allow traffic from ec2 security group.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! Really appreciate it!!